# How to run sitespeed.io in apache/ngnix server?

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, sitespeedio

I have recently heard about sitespeed.io and started using it to measure performance of my site.
I am running it in a docker container on my gcp cloud instance.

The problem is everytime i run the command it stores the result in a particular directory sitespeed-result and then I need to copy the whole thing on my local windows machine to view index.html file.

Is it possible to run this on a server like apache? I mean for example I can run an apache container on my docker host but how do i map this sitespeed io result so that it can be available using http://my-gcp-instance:80 where my apache container is running on port 80.

```
sudo docker run -v "$(pwd)":/sitespeed.io sitespeedio/sitespeed.io:13.3.0 https://mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting thr question this but I got it working.

`sudo docker run -dit --name my-apache -p 8080:80 -v "$(pwd)":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4`

(pwd) is where i am storing the sitespeed results.